# How to inject split chunk files into aspx file using webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux, webpack-4

I am using HtmlWebpackPlugin() to inject webpack chunks into html file. I want similar kind of functionality to inject webpack chunks into aspx files.

Is their similar plugin available ?.

or

What changes should I do in HtmlWebpackPlugin() ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while integrating spring boot with react app. There's a workaround you can here is your server will run `index.aspx`. You just need to include your webpack generated `index.html` into you aspx:

```
<!-- #include file="~/path/to/index.html" -->   // webpack generated
```